# How can I toggle button with key VB

Tags: vb.net

I try to toggle button with a key I can't find the solution. Can Someone help me? Here is the code of button.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        toggle = toggle + 1
        If toggle = 1 Then
            Timer1.Start()
            Button1.Text = "Status: ON"
        Else
            Timer1.Stop()
            toggle = 0
            Button1.Text = "Status: OFF"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`KeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown) or [`KeyUp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keyup) event of the `Form`:

```
'bind the KeyUp event
AddHandler Me.KeyUp, AddressOf SubToPressButton

'the Sub which is triggered by the KeyUp event
Sub SubToPressButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)

    'click button on key "A"
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub

'your Button1 click event
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    toggle += 1

    If toggle = 1 Then
        Timer1.Start()
        Button1.Text = "Status: ON"
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
        toggle = 0
        Button1.Text = "Status: OFF"
    End If
End Sub
```

You also have to enable the [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview) of the `Form`:

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
```

You can set the above line to the constructor (`New`) or `Load` event of the `Form`. You can also enable the `KeyPreview` directly on the properties of the `Form`.

---

**You need to toggle the button outside the application?**

In this case you need global keyboard hooks. You can find a solution on StackOverflow already:

- [listen for a key when the application is not focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065817/listen-for-a-key-when-the-application-is-not-focused/5065906#5065906)
- [Catching "global hotkeys" (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259322/catching-global-hotkeys-windows)

But be careful, other applications can use global or local hotkeys too.

Comment: Do i need to add Me.KeyPreview = True to Form_Load

Comment: You can set this directly on the properties of the form.

Comment: It's working now thanks but when an application is in the background then it's not working how can I have it working in background.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065817/listen-for-a-key-when-the-application-is-not-focused/5065906#5065906 (but be careful, other applications can use global or local hotkeys too).

Comment: That is c#? but I need VB

Comment: @CroatiaGM : To make it work in the background the best approach in my opinion is to use a Low-level keyboard hook (mentioned in the second bullet in Sebastian's link). My library called [InputHelper](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper) includes a fairly easy-to-use implementation of it (more details can be found [here](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/wiki/Low-level-keyboard-hook)).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably learn from the other answers - regarding KeyUp/Down events, but just to enhance your existing code, try this;

```
Private toggle As Boolean

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not toggle Then
        Timer1.Start()
        Button1.Text = "Status: ON"
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
        Button1.Text = "Status: OFF"
    End If
    toggle = Not toggle
End Sub
```

What I've done is;
  Change the toggle integer to a boolean - since it's being used as a flag
  Use that flag to toggle the timer on or off for every button click
  Invert the flag at the end of every button click

I hope that helps - but as noted above - there are better ways to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

Use an accelerator key, i.e. add an ampersand (&) to the `Text` property and you can use the subsequent character's key with the `Alt` key.

Also, instead of a `Button`, use a `Checkbox` with its `Appearance` set to `Button`.